# Storing and reading data in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm totally new to programming in java though I have worked with C++ alot before. I am trying to make a simple quiz app to begin with; I want to be it flexible, so, for example, I could keep all the questions and answers in some storage unit that could be updated and modified easily and the app would just pick up the new data without need to modify it.

The question is: how to and what is the best (and maybe simplest) way to do that?
I am trying to achieve something like that when the app is installed, all I need to do to add new questions is to somehow store it, let's say, in a file and place it somewhere maybe in the app's dir for it to read.

As I said, I'm new here, so please don't give me some really complicated pieces of code or so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Picking up new data without having to modify the app sounds like you need a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the data in the mobile app (permanently) and not retrieve it from a server.You can use some classes from the "Preference" package in android.
`SharedPreferences.Editor` to save your values and
`SharedPreferences` to get the values
here is a sample code:

```
editor.putString(editKey.getText().toString()); // putString is the method of Editor class, and in this example editkey is the field for EditText
```

The above line gets a value from an EditText (a textfield in Android) and saves it.
NOTE: You can also use SQLite database if you have large number of questions.